# Assign DatePicker Selection Value To String Array On Change SWIFTUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a date picker, when the fromDate and toDate sections changes, I would like to assign it to the myArray["fromDate"] = $fromDate, how do I do that, thank you for your time.

I tried with onTapGesture, but it crash the app when I'm selecting the dates.

```
var myArray["fromDate"] : [String: Any]

 struct myDatePicker: View {
        @State public var toDate = Date()
        
        @State public var fromDate: Date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(year: -1), to: Date()) ?? Date()
    
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack(spacing:10) {
                VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing:10) {
                    Text("Service Date Range")
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    HStack {
                        DatePicker(selection: $fromDate.onchange({ myArray["fromDate"] = $fromDate}), displayedComponents: .date) {
                            Text("From")
                                .font(.body)
                                .fixedSize()
                        }
                        DatePicker(selection: $toDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                            Text("To")
                                .font(.body)
                                .fixedSize()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding(10)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You code isn't actually showing where `myArray` is defined or what type it is.

Comment: myArray["fromDate"] = ["fromDate": "20201231" ]

Comment: That still isn't showing where you define `myArray`

Comment: myArray["fromDate"] : [String: Any]

Comment: Some where, you declare `myArray` -- it probably looks like this `var myArray` or `let myArray` and then has a type definition. Where is that defined? It seems like it would be in myDatePicker , but it's not there.

Comment: var myArray["fromDate"] : [String: Any], @jnpdx, the answer below only works for iOS version 14.0+, I need to be able to support iOS 13.

Comment: @jnpdx, or you can use the print statement. I just need to get the date picker value first for iOS 13.

Comment: I can look later today. You might want to comment on the answer (which is not mine) with this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like this:

```
DatePicker("From", selection: $fromDate)
   .onChange(of: fromDate) { myArray["fromDate"] = $0 }
```

or

```
DatePicker(selection: $fromDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
     Text("From").font(.body).fixedSize()
 }.onChange(of: fromDate) { myArray["fromDate"] = $0 }
```

Comment: thank you for taking your time! Your answer only works for iOS 14+, I also need to support the iOS 13

Answer (score 1):

The following will work in iOS 13 where you don't have access to `onChange`:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published public var toDate = Date()
    @Published var fromDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(year: -1), to: Date()) ?? Date() {
        didSet {
            //perform whatever side-effect you need here
            print("Set from date: \(fromDate)")
        }
    }
}

struct myDatePicker: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing:10) {
            VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing:10) {
                Text("Service Date Range")
                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                HStack {
                    DatePicker(selection: $viewModel.fromDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
                        Text("From")
                            .font(.body)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                    DatePicker(selection: $viewModel.toDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                        Text("To")
                            .font(.body)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding(10)
    }
}
```

I'm still not clear on where `myArray` is defined -- if it's just a global variable as you imply in the comments, you can set it inside the `didSet` that I show above.

Comment: Did this solve your issue of running on iOS 13?